# How can one have many HTML5 pages with only one navigation bar code page using ONLY html and CSS?

Tags: css, html

I have many html pages. Is it possible that I store/manage the navigation menu in one central place using ONLY HTML5 and CSS? This means all the navigation code in in one file so I don't have to edit the code on every page when a change is made to the menu.

Thanks,
Douglas

Comment: Only if you use (i)frames, and that is something you don’t want to do. Use either an editor that has the capability to include files in other files (so that the full file will be created when it is saved), or a server-side technique that can do this dynamically.

Comment: You should be able to trick something around conditional styles, css declarations based on elements statuses (:focus, :checked etc.) I think if you prepare multiple views in one a bit like a TabPanel element, showing each tabs based on conditional css, you might be able to solve this.

Comment: but if what you need is increased maintenance, why don't you just store the html code of the navigation panel outside of the page, and include it in all pages it is required?

Comment: check this https://css-tricks.com/css3-tabs/

Comment: Using CSS tabs is barely a solution when you have "many html pages".

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I have one point the I would like to have made clear. Why are iFrames considered out or no longer the right way?

Comment: Please distiguish iFrames vs. frames: The common technology 20 years ago were frames. The problem with them was that one page consisted of several HTML documents. When you set a link, often enough it would happen that this link only lead to one of those "page parts", presenting it out of context (for example without header, sidebar, or maybe even content). iFrames are intended to include part of a foreign website in your own site - the most famous example is Youtube: If you embed a video with the code Youtube provides, that's an iFrame - but you have no influence on the content of that iFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. In early 1990 people used iFrames:

```
<iframe src="menu.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="content.html" name="content"></iframe>
```

Than all menu items will have `target="content"` appended to modify iframe link.

Comment: I think you mean frames, not iframes (I was there "in early 1990"...) But people stopped doing that for good reasons.

Comment: Unfortunately "iframes" are in use until today.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your web server's capability; for example, [Apache's SSI](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/ssi.html). This is about the smallest advance you can make from frames which, as others point out, are best avoided. Server-side includes are very nearly just plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframes to do so like

```
 <iframe src="Header.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="restOfThePage.html" name="content"></iframe>
```

but this is not the best way to do so , this is how websites were built back in the days . but since you are thinking about code reuse you should consider using a templating engine like handlebars or maybe a full MVC framework like Angular . It will help you a lot building these kinds of applications and will be nice to but it on your CV as well

Answer (score 0):

There is no good solution to this using HTML and CSS only.

However, you can use a static page generator like [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), [Hexo](https://hexo.io/), or [Hugo](http://gohugo.io). With them you can specify a navigation to be included on every page and then generate the HTML/CSS files accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe to achieve your goal.

Have a navigation menu in your index.html file and an `iframe` for the pages.

The `iframe` should have a `name` attribute like so :

`<iframe name="pages" src="main.html"><iframe>`

Every link in the navigation menu should have `target` attribute with the value of `pages` (iframe's name)  for example :

`<a href="page1.html" target="pages">page 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" target="pages">page 2</a>`

This way, the links will be opened in the iframe and not in the parent page, so the navigation menu is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a forecast on another way do build up an navigation without anytools. 
It is allmost "only HTML". You can use:

```
document.write('<div id="navigation">')
document.write('<div class="navItem">Enter your HTML (HREF)...</div>')
document.write('</div>')
```

You have to save it as an javascript file:
navigation.js. Then you can include it in every html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/includes/navigation.js"></script>
```

Maybe it helps.